# migrating to adobe air

Tags: air

I don't know anything about adobe air. I have a lot of javascript code and I'm wondering if adobe air can act as a wrapper around my code. Basically, I'd like to put the javascript inside to prevent users from gaining access to the code.

Can adobe air do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could start by reading the Adobe® AIR™ for JavaScript Developers Pocket Guide.

http://onair.adobe.com/files/AIRforJSDevPocketGuide.pdf

Comment: Well I was hoping to avoid having to read all that just to find out if AIR can do what I'm looking to do by asking someone who knew. Basically, can AIR act as a wrapper and protect my code?

Comment: Well, thanks for the pointer; a boolean woulda been nicer.